# Is there any settings/option to to avoid authentication of agent after In-Person signing in DocuSign?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Every time the agent needs to login after an in-person signing operation. I wonder if there any way to avoid this authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

In Person signing requires a host, which must have a DocuSign account. The host has to authenticate like anyone using the DocuSign account. So that is subject to any of the rules of authentication. You wouldn't need to do that again if the browser is still open on your account for 8 hours. But the next day, the agent would need to authenticate again. This is a security requirement which cannot be changed.

Comment: The browser remains open and the host still has to sign-in for finishing each In Person signing which comes back to back. Is there any property/setting to achieve an authentication which lasts for 8 hr as mentioned above?

Comment: The below is the code I have used, please see if I am missing out something.. Thanks :) `InPersonSigner signer = new InPersonSigner();
signer.RecipientId = "1";
signer.RoutingOrder = "1";
signer.InPersonSigningType = "inPersonSigner";
signer.SignerName = "John Smith";
signer.HostName = "Alex";
signer.HostEmail = "alex@test.abc";`

Comment: yes, if the browser is open, you don't need to re-authenticate for 8 hours

Comment: It does not work for me. I tried both IE and Chrome browsers

Comment: ok, I think there's a misunderstanding. What does not work for you?
Open a browser, go to account-d.docusign.com, log in.
Leave the browser open!
Go back in 5 min, does it ask you to log in again?
If that's not what you mean - please explain exactly your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Inbar, Following is my scenario. I have logged into the account and leave that browser open. After 5 min I am opening my email from the same browser in another tab and trying to open an InPerson signing email request, passing control to the signer, after the signer signed the **host authentication login window comes**. Can we avoid this authentication step since the host is already logged into the same browser in some other tab less than a 5 minutes ago! _I am using demo.docusign.net account as the application is in the development phase, does that make any relevance to this issue?_

Comment: aha, ok, now I understand, that seems to be either a bug or a missing feature, I'll ask here, but I'm not sure if it's expected behavior. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you Inbar. please check with the team, we are waiting for the response.

Comment: Well, the issue here is that this is a different browser window or tab.
You can try one thing different than how you were doing it:
"I have logged into the account and leave that browser open. After 5 min I am opening my email from the same browser in *the same* tab (!!) and trying to open an InPerson signing email request, passing control to the signer..."

Comment: you can copy/paste the URL from the email into the tab that is opened in DocuSign, let me know if that worked.

Comment: Inbar, I tried the workaround you gave, copy the URL from email and paste it on the browser tab where the DocuSign host is logged in. Pass control to the signer, after signing  and click Finish button, 'Request a copy' popup arrived first and followed by  'Pass Control' popup! when I clicked continue a **new tab opened with the Log in screen of the host.** I am sorry to say this didn't work! Do we have anything else to try?

Comment: I can't get an official answer yet, I'm sorry, the information I got is that this is done for extra security. I understand how this seems to be more of an annoyance then security, but I can't yet prove that it isn't necessary.